# Can not find ASP.Net Table with FindControl method

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I find an ASP.Net table control with `FindControl` method?

```
  if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["Persons"]) == 1)
            {

                HtmlTable tt = (HtmlTable)panel1.FindControl("singleTbl");
                tt.Visible = true;
            }






<asp:UpdatePanel ID="panel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btn_serch" EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>

    <div id="div_result" runat="server" style="display:none" class="divsearchresult">
        <table width="750">
 <asp:DataList ID="dtlRoomsPrice" Visible="false" orizontalAlign="center" runat="server"
ShowFooter="False" ShowHeader="False" Width="700px" OnItemDataBound="dtlRoomsDetails_ItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
<table border="0" id="singleTbl" width="90" align="left" runat="server" style="visibility:hidden;">

</table>
</ItemTemplate>
    </table>
    </div>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: What is the main prob ?  your code will find `singleTbl` if it is exist.

Comment: the problem i can not find the singletbl control this control is table

Comment: Make sure `singleTable` is exist , you can do find in singleTbl's parent. e.g `(Table)Panel1.FindControl("singleTbl");`

Comment: Is there exception ? set `breakpoint` on if block and debug it line by line.

Comment: still not working with your code

Comment: yes i debug it the value returned with null

Comment: You can not cast an `ASP.Net` control to HTML control or vise versa.

Comment: @Aria that is the first point i have mentioned.

Comment: No you said how to find ASP.Net control but you added an HTML control , apart this you just edited your question. you did't add your HTML code first.

Comment: @Aria i said i have mentioned that in my answer. i m not the person who asks this question

Comment: @Med.Amine.Touil Aha excuse me I didn't see at the first go, if you want I can remove the comment ?

Comment: @Aria No prob Bro :)

Comment: i can not talk on chat from the "stackoverflow "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problem with your code ,

First you can not cast an `ASP.Net` control to HTML control or vise versa

so your table is HTML control you need cast it to `HtmlControl` like:

```
 HtmlControl tt = (HtmlControl)FindControl("singleTbl"); 
    tt.Visible = true;
```

second you have designed a table HTML tag which have not any `tr` and `td` so change it like :

```
<table border="0" id="singleTbl" width="90" align="left" runat="server" style= "display:none;">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

It is proffered to use `display` instead of `visibility` because `display:none;` hides an element, and it will not take up any space so you can try like:

```
   HtmlControl tt = (HtmlControl)FindControl("singleTbl");
        tt.Style.Add("display", "block");
        //tt.Attributes["visibility"] = "visible";
        //tt.Attributes["display"] = "block";
        //tt.Visable = true;
```

or you should do it in `ItemDataBound` event of `DataList` as following:

```
HtmlControl tt = (HtmlControl)e.Item.FindControl("singleTbl");
tt.Style.Add("display", "block");
```

Comment: Ok lets do it together , Where you are going to find `Table` I mean which even ? `RowDataBound` or `DataBound` or ... ?

Comment: in a separate  button click?

Comment: yes this function i call it inside button_click event

Comment: If your design code is exactly that in your question post then you didn't close tag of `DataList` and `ContentTemplate` of `UpdatePanel` .

Comment: i want to add another css property with this property how ?

Comment: @boshkashh You can add an exist `css` instead of property  `tt.Style.Add("Class", "your_Css_selector");`

Comment: tt.Style.Add("Class", "singTbl"); like this

Comment: Yes if you have something like `.singTbl {
                border: 1px solid #ddd;
                margin: 4px 8px 6px 0px;
                width: 95px;
                height: 60px;
                float: left; 
            }` in your CSS style.

Answer (score 0):

The method "FindControl" searches the first level controls under the container . Maybe your table is enjected dynamically after a postback or it 's under an other control like Panel or UpdatePanel.

First of all your table  is a HTML table so singleTbl is a `HtmlTable` not `Table`.
If you want it a `Table` Class you must use `<asp:Table>` tag.
Second point your tag `<contenttemplate>` is not closed.

The last point, i mentioned that the FindControl sheaches only in the direct children of the control.

you must add runat server and an Id to your first div and table

then in your code:

```
 var div= Panel1.FindControl("divID") as HtmlGenericControl;
 var firstTable=div.FindControl("firstTableID") as HtmlTable;
 var dataList=firstTable.findControl("dtlRoomsPrice") as DataList;
 var tbl=dataList.FindControl("singleTbl") as HtmlTable;
```

Comment: First parentID is not a function or a class;
it's the name of your table's parent.

let's say you are injecting your table inside a panel
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Pnl">
</asp:Panel>

so your FirstParentID=Pnl

Comment: Table tt = (Table)panel1.FindControl("singleTbl"); like this .?

Comment: tt value returnd with null

Comment: Your table exists inside Panel1 ?

Comment: The code you wrote in your question is it inside a web method , or ButtonClick eventHundler, Is there any update panel ?

Comment: my code is inside method and this method i called it inside btn_click event handler and i have update panel this table i want it inside the update panel

Comment: Can you edit your question and show as your asp code?

Comment: @boshkashh take a look at my edit answer. Hope it helps and pay tension to your html code hierarchy.

Normally it will work know